# Trying to install W10-IoT on my new RP3-B.

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, windows-iot

Using the NOOBS loader because it's what I know. Decided to go with Raspbian AND W10... Everything fine until I instinctively copied the Microsoft license agreement so I could paste it to a bigger window and seriously read it. After selecting the entire agreement and then realizing there's nothing to paste it to and THEN hitting ESC to deselect, the installation script for W10-IoT was promptly interrupted. The system suggested I hold shift on reboot to resume but that didn't work. So now I have Raspbian running (no complaint there) but I don't know how to resume my installation of W10. Can someone advise?

Oh, and sorry for the long explanation (I thought it would be shorter).

Comment: Is using NOOBS a requirement. You can you `Windows 10 iot core dashboard` to install Windows 10 iot.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen NOOBS say to hold shift on boot to resume installation, BUT: If you hold shift when the screen says "for recovery mode, hold shift" the NOOBS os installer shows up. Check the boxes for win10IoT and Raspbian and press install and they should start reinstall (though this will wipe the SD card).

Comment: Thank you Marc. I was using a wireless keyboard with a weak battery, perhaps the "shift" key wasn't getting through. I'm back to installing W10 IoT now. :)

Comment: i think timing is everything....you need to hold shift when it actually says it and not before. Pressing the "3" button before you hold down shift helps can't remember the explanation but something to do with an option